# Geometry Nodes - How to Scale Instances Incrementally?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In a geometry node setup such as this, which nodes can you connect to the Scale input to make it so each instance is scaled incrementally (e.g. 10% smaller than the instance before it)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an exponential reduction in scale:

[image]

For more even spacing, you can modify the locations in parallel:

[image]

Comment: *lol* I finished mine almost at the same time, but somehow I read the question wrong and upscaled by 10% :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hehe.. only an 'e.g' in OP .. don't think that matters.. :)

Comment: Didn't even realize that ;) Anyway, no offense to the asker, this is more an observation I make now and then: people ask for something in general and give an example, but tend to be either helpless when you don't address this specific case or the other option is, their example is so far from what they actually want to do, that the general solution doesn't work there or at least it's not the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for this Robin.  Especially the bit about the positioning which is also paramount to what I'm trying to do.  I'm having a hard time understanding how the GN's share data.  My brain always thinks of data being handed over to the right, but in some instances (like your even spacing solution) it appears that data is also handed to the left, which I am still trying to wrap my head around.

Comment: Hi @glen_candle! Thanks for that.. the spacing is actually a bit of a hack, you may be better of using _Accumulate Field_ to be more general. I'll replace the example when I get a chance.

Comment: @glen_candle see edit.

Comment: Looks very elegant.  I'm definitely interesting in learning more about the Accumulate Field node, seems very powerful.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Somehow I set my mind on upscaling instead of downscaling... so Robin's answer is correct. Mine just adds the mathematical explanation why to use a *Power* node. Maybe this is useful information for some people so I'll leave it here.

To scale something up by 10%, speaking mathematically it is multiplying the dimensions by 1.1 as a factor. Repeating it *n* times results in multiplying the initial value by (1.1)^*n*, so you can simply put this in a *Math* node.

The only thing you need now is some kind of counter for the steps. The *ID* node comes in quite handy for this, usually the instances are numbered 0, 1, 2 etc.

So, take a *Math* node set to *Power*, enter 1.1 as *Base* value and plug the ID into the *Exponent* input.

[image: upscaling]

The first ID gives (1.1)^0 = 1, this is the initital original size, let's say *x*. Next up is (1.1)^1 = 1.1, makes the second cube 1.1**x*. The third cube should be 1.1*(1.1**x*) = 1.21**x*, and since 1.21 = (1.1)^2 this is what you get.

If your instances are somewhere inbetween other geometry and the ID doesn't start at 0, you can first put a *Subtract* node after the *ID* node to "reset" it to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gordon.  What is the difference between the ID node and the Index node (used in Robin's answer)?  Is there a way to see the data on which vertex/point is assigned which Index/ID?

Comment: @glen_candle Well, the _Index_ node uses the index which indicates the position of each element following the internal order of data, every element has an index number. The _ID_  node gives the value of the _id_ attribute which doesn't necessarily have to exist on element. They can also be assigned through the _Set ID_ node. If no specific ID is assigned, this node will also output the index number. The index is the left-most column in the _Spreadsheet_. If an ID exists, it will be shown in a different column titled "id".

Comment: @glen_candle Most of the time you won't need the ID, but since it gives the same value as the index you can use either one or the other. You can read about them in the Blender manual: [Index Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/input_index.html), [ID Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/id.html) and the [Set ID Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/set_id.html). But I don't think the explanations make it really clear what to use the different nodes for.

Comment: This is great information, thanks @Gordon Brinkmann.  Actually has helped my understanding much more than the manual ;)

Comment: @glen_candle I would'nt mind to elaborate this ID/Index thing further with examples, but I guess this would go beyond the scope of this question.