# How do you scale instances of geometry nodes from small to big, without scaling the entire geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes, transforms, instances

Pardon my ignorance, I'm a total noob at blender and this is my second project with geometry nodes.

I've tried following this: https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/sliding-instances-along-a-curve-in-blender-using-geometry-nodes/ and then this tutorial [Geometry Nodes - How to Scale Instances Incrementally?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272409/geometry-nodes-how-to-scale-instances-incrementally)
But if I replace the circle with a spiral, when I change the scale, I notice it affects the spiral itself (gets longer) too.
It also weirdly affects the angle of the spiral.

[image: Spiral with sphere instances]

[image: Geometry nodes setup]

I think it affects the whole spiral, not just the sphere instances.
Anyway, some insight would be nice on how I can change the scale of the spheres without affecting anything else.

Comment: I don't get any distortion on the spiral at all: https://i.imgur.com/bVRwu0o.gif Your Scale socket is only fed by an Index through Float Curve so it couldn't affect the spiral. Maybe something's going on with your object outside Geometry Nodes. You could share the file itself (https://blend-exchange.com/) so people could take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your *Geometry Nodes* setup in this case is completely correct, and it works as it should.

Only the node `Value` could be replaced with `Integer`, but this is rather cosmetic.

The real problem in this case is the center of the object, which is a little off here.

[image]

You have several ways to correct this, and one of them would be:

Choose *Snap To > Snap Origin > Geometry to Origin* in *Edit Mode*.

*(You can open this context menu with <kbd>Space</kbd>)*.